# Can't parse different product links from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script in Python to fetch different product links from a webpage. Although I know the content of that site are dynamic, I tried conventional way to let you inform that I tried. I looked for APIs in the dev tools but could not find one. Ain't there any way to get those links using requests?

[Site Link](https://www.amazon.com/stores/node/10699640011)

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.amazon.com/stores/node/10699640011"

def fetch_product_links(url):
    res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item_link in soup.select("[id^='ProductGrid-'] li[class^='style__itemOuter__'] > a"):
        print(item_link.get("href"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_product_links(link)
```

How can I fetch different product links from that site using requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you only need the asins which you can collect from another url construct you can see in network tab i.e. you can significantly shorten the final urls. You do however need to make a request to your original url to pick up an identifier to use in second url. Returns 146 links.

```
import requests, re, json

node = '10699640011'

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/stores/node/{node}')
    p = re.compile(r'var slotsStr = "\[(.*?,){3} share\]";')
    identifier = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    identifier = identifier.strip()[:-1]
    r = s.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/stores/slot/{identifier}?node={node}')
    p = re.compile(r'var config = (.*?);')
    data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
    asins = data['content']['ASINList']
    links = [f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}' for asin in asins]
    print(links)
```

---

EDIT:

With two given nodes:

```
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

nodes = ['3039806011','10699640011']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for node in nodes:
        r = s.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/stores/node/{node}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        identifier = soup.select('.stores-widget-btf:not([id=share],[id*=RECOMMENDATION])')[-1]['id']
        r = s.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/stores/slot/{identifier}?node={node}')
        p = re.compile(r'var config = (.*?);')
        data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
        asins = data['content']['ASINList']
        links = [f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}' for asin in asins]
        print(links)
```

Comment: Incredibly awesome @QHarr. Thanks a zillion.

Comment: hopefully it works across links. The first regex could be improved.

Comment: An optional requests if you have time @QHarr. How about this node `3039806011`?

Comment: I will have a look a little later today if that is ok?

Comment: I need to alter the first regex.

Comment: I have updated for the two nodes given but may need to see more nodes

Comment: Yes, it does work even when I use both of the nodes. One last thing - could you tell me how I can find that `https://www.amazon.com/stores/slot/---` in dev tools. Is it within xhr under network tab? Thanks.

Comment: yes ^^. Refresh the page then search for one of the asins off the page in the network search box.

Comment: My head is spinning to fetch price from where you parsed the asins @QHarr. The problem is the target page `https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DOLQ0BY` do not contain price, so I need to parse the price from it's landing page `https://www.amazon.com/stores/node/10699640011`.

Comment: I'm dredfully sorry that I put a lot of pressure on you concerning this. Thanks a lot for your concern.

Comment: It's not a problem :-)